# Sum of the terms of an AP

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

Here is an 
$$AP:10,13,...,94,$$ where $$a=10, d=3$$ and $$a_n=l=94$$

So for finding the sum of first 14 terms:

$$Sn = n/2 *[2a+(n-1)d] = 14/2 * [2*10+(14-1)3] = 413$$
$$Sn = n/2 *[a+l]  =  14/2 * [10+94] = 728$$

Why am I getting 2 different answers? Where am I wrong? I have checked many times but still can't find my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that 94 is the 14th term but first check whether 94 is really the 14th term

We have $$a_n=a+(n-1)d$$
$$94=10+(n-1)3$$

$$84=(n-1)3$$

$$n=29$$

Thus 94 is not 14th term it is 29th term so you are summing till the 29th term

Comment: oh! That's what was wrong.

Comment: yes you are summing till 29th term and you calculation for summing till 14th term is correct